# Example for cognito login using SWIFT & Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a sample iOS application for listing S3 bucket after login from facebook using amazon cognito. unfortunately I can not found any examples in swift for cognito authentication through facebook. The one provided in the example doesn’t take care of the authentication part.

Can anybody provide sample code for this.

So bad that amazon is not even providing a good example in swift covering major services.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Set the AWS credentials provider to use Facebook's auth token
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
    regionType: CognitoRegionType, 
    identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityPoolId)
let logins: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary: 
    ["graph.facebook.com" : self.fbToken])
credentialProvider.logins = logins as [NSObject : AnyObject]
credentialProvider.refresh()
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
    region: DefaultServiceRegionType,
    credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Where self.fbToken is the Facebook token, and CognitoRegionType, CognitoIdentityPoolId, and DefaultServiceRegionType are all defined constants.

Comment: but what about the custom class where we need to implement refresh function?

Comment: Hi i am going to integrate AWS login to my application please help me to do?

Comment: unfortunately this example is out of date

Answer (score 2):

There is one Swift example in the AWS iOS samples repository at this time, but it is for demonstrating SNS. It doesn't show S3 or Facebook Login, but it does show Cognito.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/SNS-MobileAnalytics-Sample/Swift/

Comment: as you said it never shows how we can assign fb token to cognito. Trying to find documentation for swift. Please let me know if you have any sample

Comment: This forum post shows you how to set the facebook token in the logins map: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=167189&tstart=0  It may get you one step closer.